# Why does 'return' and 'yield return' have the same behaviour in this example?

Tags: c#, linq

I was reading this [article about fluent-style syntax](http://csharp.2000things.com/2014/10/03/1196-using-fluent-style-syntax-when-chaining-iterators/) and I tried the example. I noticed that when I converted the `YoungDogs()` and `HerdingDogs()` method bodies to LINQ expressions the `yield return` was replaced with `return`, but the behaviour of the method stayed the same.

Why does changing the method to a LINQ expression change the behaviour of how the data is returned?

This is the original example as outlined in the article:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Dog> YoungDogs(this IEnumerable<Dog> dogs)
    {
        foreach (Dog d in dogs)
            if (d.Age < 10)
                yield return d;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Dog> HerdingDogs(this IEnumerable<Dog> dogs)
    {
        foreach (Dog d in dogs)
            if ((d.Breed == Breed.BorderCollie) ||
                (d.Breed == Breed.Collie) ||
                (d.Breed == Breed.Sheltie))
                yield return d;
    }
```

This is the full program with the changed methods:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (Dog d in AllMyDogs().YoungDogs().HerdingDogs())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
            if (d.Breed == Breed.JackRussell)
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Dog> AllMyDogs()
    {
        yield return new Dog("Kirby", Breed.BorderCollie, 14);
        yield return new Dog("Jack", Breed.JackRussell, 15);
        yield return new Dog("Ruby", Breed.Mutt, 4);
        yield return new Dog("Lassie", Breed.Collie, 19);
        yield return new Dog("Shep", Breed.Collie, 2);
        yield return new Dog("Foofoo", Breed.Sheltie, 8);
        yield return new Dog("Pongo", Breed.Dalmatian, 4);
        yield return new Dog("Rooster", Breed.WestHighlandTerrier, 1);
    }
}

static class DogFilters
{
    public static IEnumerable<Dog> YoungDogs(this IEnumerable<Dog> dogs)
    {
        return dogs.Where(d => d.Age < 10);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Dog> HerdingDogs(this IEnumerable<Dog> dogs)
    {
        return dogs.Where(d => (d.Breed == Breed.BorderCollie) ||
                               (d.Breed == Breed.Collie) ||
                               (d.Breed == Breed.Sheltie));
    }
}

public enum Breed
{
    BorderCollie,
    Collie,
    Sheltie,
    JackRussell,
    Mutt,
    Dalmatian,
    WestHighlandTerrier
}

public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Breed Breed { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Dog(string name, Breed breed, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Breed = breed;
        Age = age;
    }

    public bool TryBark(out string barkSound)
    {
        bool success = false;
        barkSound = "";

        if (Age <= 10)
        {
            success = true;
            barkSound = "Woof";
        }

        return success;
    }

    public string Bark()
    {
        string barkSound;

        if (!TryBark(out barkSound))
            throw new Exception("This dog can't bark");
        return barkSound;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} <{1}>, age {2}", Name, Breed.ToString(), Age);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Where` method encapsulates the `yield`.

Comment: Check out Jon Skeet's edulinq series.  He does a good job of explaining the details of how Linq is implemented.  Here's the link to the part on `Where` http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/02-Where.html.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Not really. You could use the `Where` and still use `yield return`, you could *not* use `Where` and still use `return`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `dogs.Where(d => d.Age < 10);` declares a sequence, which when `YoungDogs` will be called will be returned. The thing that will be returned is the declaration of the sequence, not the dogs that "*pass your filter*". You will get the actual objects from `dogs` collection, only when you request them.

Under the hood `Where` encapsulates the call to the `yield return` through which the items in `dogs` that passes the predicate get returned one after the other. That happens for inastance below:

```
// That declares the sequence, you want to get. 
// In dogsWithAgeLessThanTen you don't have actaully any dog.
var dogsWithAgeLessThanTen = dogs.Where(d => d.Age < 10);

// Now you request the above query to be executed, that's called lazy loading. 
// Here you get one after the other the dogs that have age less than 10.
// The Enumerator you get from the dogsWithAgeLessThanTen returns your data 
// through a yield return statement.
foreach(var dog in dogsWithAgeLessThanTen)
{

}
```

The above is the same, regarding the results taht will be returned with the below one:

```
public static IEnumerable<Dog> YoungDogs(this IEnumerable<Dog> dogs)
{
    foreach (Dog d in dogs)
        if (d.Age < 10)
            yield return d;
}

var dogsWithAgeLessThanTen = dogs.YoungDogs();

foreach(var dog in dogsWithAgeLessThanTen)
{

}
```